# Generic Setup of Quartz.NET tasks

Tags: cron, quartz.net

The regular setup of Quartz cron-based tasks looks like this:

```
IJobDetail firstJob = JobBuilder.Create<FirstJob>()
               .WithIdentity("firstJob")
               .Build();

ITrigger firstTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                 .WithIdentity("firstTrigger")
                 .StartNow()
                 .WithCronSchedule("0 * 8-22 * * ?")
                 .Build();
```

`FirstJob` is a specific class that implements `IJob` interface from Quartz. In my case I may have multiple job classes implementing that interface, each does particular type of work that needs to be scheduled.

Therefore seems I'm forced to set up as many job detail instances as I have job classes, i.e. repeat the code. Is there any other way to simplify and shorten it and have a collection of job detail objects not implicitly passing the job class names? Say, all my job classed would implement a `CustomInterface : IJob`, and I would rather use `CustomInterface` name somewhere setting up the job details.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

```
 IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(Type.GetType(jobDetail.JobKey.Name))
```